# Consistent extraction of data from tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to extract the data from a tensorflow dataset consistently into numpy arrays/tensors. I'm loading pictures witn

```
data = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  './data', 
  labels='inferred', 
  label_mode='binary', 
  validation_split=0.2, 
  subset="training", 
  image_size=(img_height, img_width), 
  batch_size=sz_batch, 
  crop_to_aspect_ratio=True
)
```

I already got the hint to use the following lines:

```
xdata = np.concatenate([x for x, y in data], axis=0)
ydata = np.concatenate([y for x, y in data], axis=0)
```

The problem is, however, that the extracted data in `xdata` and `ydata` is not consistent, hence, the labels in `ydata` don't fit to the samples in `xdata` (I checked this by simply looping through the extracted data).

My second idea was to extract the data in a standard for loop:

```
xdata = np.empty([sz1, sz2, 3])[np.newaxis,...]
ydata = np.array([0])
for images, labels in val_ds:
    xdata = np.concatenate((xdata, images), axis=0)
    ydata = np.concatenate((ydata, labels), axis=0)

xdata = xval[1:]
ydata = yval[1:]
```

Even though the data seem to be consistent with this approach, I think this way is quite cumbersome and it's also not nicely (and supposingly also not efficiently) written - especially the last two lines bother me. But I wasn't able to come up with an easier way to extract the data and stack the extracted data together in numpy arrays/tensors.

I'd be greatful for help how to solve this problem properly in python.

Anyway, I'm wondering why the handling with the tensorflow dataset is, at least in my opinion, really cumbersome. Firstly, I need to solve the problem stated above to use the data in other routines rather than in tensorflow. Secondly, even if I use the data anywhere else than for training in tensorflow, it's not really straightforward in my optinion. E.g. if I want to compare predicted labels from a NN with the true labels from a dataset I can't easily extract the consistent labels of this dataset. I have to predict each sample separately in a for loop.

Note: I won't/can't use `tfds`

Comment: You need to iterate over the dataset if it is shuffled. You may use lists instead of arrays for appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the order of your dataset when converting it to numpy arrays, make sure you set `shuffle=False` in `image_dataset_from_directory` if you want to see the same results:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  shuffle=False)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
images, labels = next(iter(train_ds.take(1)))
image = images[0]
plt.title('label :: ' + str(labels[0]))
plt.imshow(image.numpy())
```

[image]

Afterwards, you can try a couple methods to convert your dataset into list or array-like structures:

**Option 1:**

```py
train_ds = train_ds.unbatch()
data = list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (x, y)))
data = list(map(list, zip(*data)))
images, labels = data[0], data[1]

image = images[0]
plt.title('label :: ' + str(labels[0]))
plt.imshow(image.numpy())
```

**Option 2:**

```py
import numpy as np

train_ds = train_ds.unbatch()
images = np.asarray(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)))
labels = np.asarray(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))
image = images[0]
plt.title('label :: ' + str(labels[0]))
plt.imshow(image)
```

**Option 3:**

```py
import numpy as np

# no unbatching
images = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)))
labels = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))

image = images[0]
plt.title('label :: ' + str(labels[0]))
plt.imshow(image)
```

All options will maintain the order of your data:

[image]

**Update 1:**
You could also try using `tf.TensorArray` and set `shuffle=True`:

```py
images = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
labels = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)

for x, y in train_ds.unbatch():
  images = images.write(images.size(), x)
  labels = labels.write(labels.size(), y)

images = tf.stack(images.stack(), axis=0)
labels = tf.stack(labels.stack(), axis=0)
```

Comment: Setting `shuffle=False` is not really a way I want to go because then I manually have to shuffle the dataset after the extraction (the data in the directory is ordered), hence, I have to shuffle it twice. If I'd disable shuffling, my solution in the second code block would work too.

Comment: Have you tried using TensorArrays? Check my updated answer.

Comment: This seems to work properly. Thanks a lot!